# PHP Redirection containing parameters

Tags: php, variables, redirect

I wish to create a simple php script which takes 2 variables and redirect to a certain URL format,

e.g. http://example.com/redirect.php?folder=orange&ID=19

will redirect to say http://123.122.1.12/folder=orange&ID=19

where "orange" and "19" are the two variables (no space)

another thinking is that I can pass the whole string "folder=orange&ID=19" as one variable but it contains = and & so I don't know if it is possible as it may confuse the system when used in the URL,

Can someone give me a script (redirect.php) that can do the above please? thanks!

Comment: take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Your question, as asked, is basically: "I was thinking of a way to do this, but I doubt it'll work.  Someone please do it for me."  What happens when you *actually try*?  Do you encounter an *actual problem*?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a *give me the code* kind of girl.

Comment: No, we can not give you the script.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `http_build_query` function, so you can do it this way:

```
header('Location: http://123.122.1.12/?' . http_build_query($_GET));
```

or

```
header('Location: http://123.122.1.12/?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

Answer (score 0):

after more research and trial and error, the easiest solution is parse the whole string as one variable as in this URL

example.com/redirect.php?sx=folder%3Dkodak%26ID%3D19

```
<?php
header( 'Location: http://127.0.0.1/?'. $_GET["sx"] ) ;
?>
```

the key is to encode the = and & symbols in the URL so they can be seen as a string not codes.